# Can the Samsung Gear S2/S3 be charged with Apple Watch magnetic puck charger?

Tags: apple-watch

As the title states,

Can the Samsung Gear S2/S3 be charged with Apple Watch magnetic puck charger? I do not have the equipment to test this and I have not been able to find if the Apple Watch's magnetic charger abides by the Qi standard.

I know that Samsung's Gear S3 watch receiver abides by Qi standards and can be charged by any wireless transmitter. However based on Apple's record of preferring to only handshake with their own hardware I am curious.

Comment: See this [link](http://bfy.tw/C7Xp)

Comment: Apple are using version 1.1.2 of Qi, but the software stack has been altered on the Watch so that only Apple’s charger works with the Watch. I am wanting to find out if the charger's handshake is exclusive to the Watch.

Comment: I'm also curious, however I think it's unlikely. "Based on Apple's record of preferring to only handshake with their own hardware."

Comment: I found a mate who had both and he confirmed that his Apple magnetic charger did not work with the Samsung Gear S3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it won't. I have gear S3 and my wife has apple watch series 4. Apple puck won't charge S3.